# jquery datepicker range disable field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 input fields. One is for a datepicker range and the other is for datepicker month only.  I want the month input field (also month datepicker) to become disabled if a user selects a date range... ive tried many things and tried searching but no luck.. maybe someone can turn me in the right direction..

in simple terms... if someone selects 1st input field (#daterange) then I want the 2nd input field (#monthselect) to be disabled and i want datepicker disabled on #monthselect

thanks

jquery datepicker:

```
new Picker.Date.Range($$('input[id="daterange"]'), {
        timePicker: false,
        columns: 2,
        format: '%Y/%m/%d',
        positionOffset: {x: 0, y: 0},
        onSelect: function(date){
        $('#monthselect').attr("disabled",true);
        }
    });

new Picker.Date($$('input[id="monthselect"]'), {
    positionOffset: {x: 0, y: 0},
    pickOnly: 'years',
    pickOnly: 'months',
    format: '%Y/%m',
    useFadeInOut: !Browser.ie
    });
```

my input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" style="width: 200px">

<input type="text" name="monthselect" id="monthselect">
```

This works for me (Thanks Andrew Donald Johnson):

```
new Picker.Date.Range($$('#daterange'), {
        timePicker: false,
        columns: 2,
        format: '%Y/%m/%d',
        positionOffset: {x: 0, y: 0},
        onSelect: function(date){
        document.getElementById("monthselect").disabled = true;     
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. So you want a date range, start in the first input, end in the second input, right? what else?

Comment: no. in simple terms... if someone selects 1st input field (#daterange) then I want the 2nd input field (#monthselect) to be disabled and i want datepicker disabled on #monthselect

Comment: So if the first is selected, then disable the second?

Comment: yes, its probably really simple too.. i just cant figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help you!

```
var data_01 = document.getElementById("daterange");
data_01.onchange = function () {
   if (this.value != "") {
      document.getElementById("monthselect").disabled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Comment: Question is about jquery and datepicker and a your solution is in javascript

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in the comments, here is what you asked for

```
$('#daterange').datepicker({
        timePicker: false,
        columns: 2,
        format: '%Y/%m/%d',
        positionOffset: {x: 0, y: 0},
        onSelect: function(date){
        $('#monthselect').attr("disabled",true);
        }
    });

$('#monthselect').datepicker({
    positionOffset: {x: 0, y: 0},
    pickOnly: 'years',
    pickOnly: 'months',
    format: '%Y/%m',
    //useFadeInOut: !Browser.ie
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdhb9/1/